# Multidimensional array is repeating vectors

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, random

I have the following code that takes random values from one list and puts them in an multi-dimensional array, which I use it to create a PDF:

```
protected void ConstruirExamenesAndGenerarPdf(int[] idUnidades, int numeroExamenes, int numeroReactivos)
{
    var modeloReactivos   = new ModeloReactivos();
    var reactivosUnidades = modeloReactivos.ObtenerReactivosPorIdsUnidades(idUnidades);

    var examenes = ConstruirExamenes(reactivosUnidades, numeroExamenes, numeroReactivos);

    GenerarPdf(examenes, reactivosUnidades);
}


private int[][] ConstruirExamenes(List<Reactivo> reactivosUnidades, int numeroExamenes, int numeroReactivos)
{
    var cantidadObligatorios   = reactivosUnidades.Where(r => r.obligatorio == (byte)Reactivo.Obligatoria.Si).Count();
    var cantidadNoObligatorios = reactivosUnidades.Where(r => r.obligatorio == (byte)Reactivo.Obligatoria.No).Count();

    var indicesObligatorios   = Enumerable.Range(0, cantidadObligatorios - 1).ToArray();
    var indicesNoObligatorios = Enumerable.Range(indicesObligatorios.Length, cantidadNoObligatorios - 1).ToArray();

    var examenes = new int[numeroExamenes][];

    for (var indiceExamen = 0; indiceExamen < numeroExamenes; indiceExamen++)
    {
        examenes[indiceExamen] = ConstruirExamen(indicesObligatorios, indicesNoObligatorios, numeroReactivos);
    }

    return examenes;
}

protected int[] ConstruirExamen(int[] indicesObligatorios, int[] indicesNoObligatorios, int numeroReactivos)
{
    var examen = new List<int>();

    AgregarReactivosAleatorios(examen, indicesObligatorios, numeroReactivos);
    AgregarReactivosAleatorios(examen, indicesNoObligatorios, numeroReactivos);

    return examen.ToArray();
}

private static void AgregarReactivosAleatorios(List<int> examen, int[] indicesReactivos, int numeroReactivos)
{

    var random = new Random();
    var actual = indicesReactivos.Length;

    for (var i = examen.Count; i < numeroReactivos && i < indicesReactivos.Length; i++)
    {
        var indexReactivoSeleccionar = random.Next(actual);

        var agregarEn = random.Next(0, examen.Count + 1);

        examen.Insert(agregarEn, indicesReactivos[indexReactivoSeleccionar]);

        indicesReactivos[indexReactivoSeleccionar] = indicesReactivos[--actual];
        indicesReactivos[actual]                   = examen[agregarEn];
    }
}
```

While debugging, if I put a breakpoint right before generating the pdf and inspect the array, it looks something like this:

```
[ [1,15,42,58],
  [8,9,52,69],
  [1,15,42,58],
  [8,9,52,69] ]
```

Note that rows 1 and 3 are equal, as are 2 and 4. If I instead put the breakpoint every time that a vector is created, the values do not seem to repeat. What is causing this?

Comment: How is this method called?

Comment: If the method is called several times then you should not create the `Random` instance in the method. Use a single `Random` instance. The reason is that creating several instances of `Random` in quick succession using the default constructor will lead to them having the same seed and thus producing the same sequence of random numbers.

Comment: But when I put a break point every time that a vector is created, it has diferent sequence of random numbers.

Comment: The default constructor for `Random` uses a time-dependent seed (see [the MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx)). When you break each time a vector created, the calls to the constructor as spaced further apart in time. Hence they have different seed values and generate different random sequences.

Comment: @odyss-jii you should post an answer since you were the first one to point out the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is called several times then you should not create the `Random` instance in the method. Use a single `Random` instance. The reason is that creating several instances of `Random` in quick succession using the default constructor will lead to them having the same seed and thus producing the same sequence of random numbers.